# Confusion in time complexity

Tags: c++, algorithm, time, time-complexity

How would be the time complexity of below program `O(n^2)`?

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i += c) {
   for (int j = i+1; j <=n; j += c) {
      // some O(1) expressions
   }
}
```

The second `for` loop won't execute right as in the condition `j <= n`,the value of j will always be greater than n.
Check the 3rd point in this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/)

Comment: Something looks wrong here. Maybe they meant `i -= c` in the first loop?

Comment: odd set of loops - outer one appears to be counting down, the inner one counting up - by their conditions - yet both are incrementing (up) with the same value - or decrementing if the value is negative.  Are you sure you got the right example here?

Comment: yes @davidbak the example is right.I guess there is a  typing error in the original link.

Comment: sadly there are in fact errors on the internet ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event that `n` and `c` are positive numbers, then yes the second for loop won't execute.

It appears to me that those for loops were written incorrectly in that link.

Answer (score 0):

I think what the author actually means here is

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i -= c) {
   for (int j = i+1; j <=n; j += c) {
      // some O(1) expressions
}
```

In this way, the complexity is (1+`n/c`)*(`n/2c`) = `O(n^2)`